# Upload lower version of a NuGet package to the NuGet site

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

Is it possible to add the lower version of a library as a NuGet package on the https://www.nuget.org/ site?

For example, I have already uploaded versions:

- 1.1
- 1.1.1
- 1.1.2
- 1.1.3
- 1.2

Now I need to add the version 1.1.4.

How can I do this?
Will the Visual Studio NuGet manager return 1.2 as the latest version by default? Or will it change on 1.1.4?

Comment: Yes, you can add 1.1.4 library, just as any other versions. What's the problem exactly? Default in VS manager will be the highest version - 1.2.0 in this case.

Comment: @Peska Thank you for the clarification. Never tried this before.